# Does Directx version depends on graphic card?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, opengl, directx, api

I am trying to understand how graphic cards and cpu interacts. Now i understand that there is program (running on cpu) called device (in this case graphic card) driver that sends commands to graphic card. When other program wants to display something it won`t talk to device driver directly, but talks to API (OpenGL, Directx), which then talk directly to graphic card driver. So Directx or OpenGL depends on driver, because graphic card just executes instructions from driver. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Why does hardware have to support those  API`s if it just executes instructions from driver.

Comment: Take a feature like shaders, for example.  First, the hardware must support shaders.  The device manufacturer then creates a driver that exposes that functionality to the host system in a way that interoperates with the DirectX/OpenGL APIs.  Then software on the host can then use DirectX/OpenGL APIs to access those hardware features.

Comment: Each version of DirectX and OpenGL offers access to new hardware features.  Trying to use new APIs on older hardware that doesn't support those new features will not not work.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the title question, yes the version of the API (DirectX or OpenGL) supported by a given card is dependant on the physical hardware.  In a majority of cases a new API version will require new hardware for full compatability.

The device driver, isn't really issuing commands, the commands are already issued by the API, the driver in a way, manipulates those commands to make best use of the underlying hardware.  It does a lot more than that as well like manage the interaction at the OS level.

Comment: So...for every feature in API (OpenGL,DirectX) there must be driver that know about it and graphic card that knows how to do it.

Comment: @Ramhound I know this is 2 year old post, but I somehow ended on this question. The reason I was confused is that much of the commands in OpenGL expose hardware acceleration capabilities. This means that those commands could be executed on the CPU as well, so if the graphics card wouldn't have hardware capabilities for that accelaration, CPU could still execute those commands.

Comment: @Ramhound Mistakenly posted unfinished comment, deleting this one, but the original comment is finished

Comment: "This means that those commands could be executed on the CPU as well" -   Actually that wouldn't happen.  The x86 architecture **cannot** process OpenGL commands, a embedded GPU within a x86 CPU (if it exists) could, but which version of OpenGL (and thus which command) was supported would entirely depend on the GPU hardware itself not the CPU.  I might not agree with the wording of this answer, but the underline statement that DX and OpenGL both require hardware support, is accurate.